# Hover на slick-слайдер

Tags: slick.js

Для перелистывания слайдера использую `cssEase:'linear'` и когда навожу на элемент - появляется `box-shadow`, позиция мышки остается на слайде. Слайдер при этом продолжает скроллиться и `box-shadow` скроллится вместе со слайдером, но позиция мышки остается неизменной.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.your-class').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        speed: 4000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        cssEase:'linear'
    });
});
```

```css
.your-class div {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
}
.your-class div:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 55px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 55px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 20px 55px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.14/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.14/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="your-class">
  <div>aaaaa aaaaaaa</div>
  <div>bbbbb bbbbbbb</div>
  <div>ccccc ccccccc</div>
  <div>ddddd ddddddd</div>
  <div>eeeee eeeeeee</div>
  <div>fffff fffffff</div>
  <div>ggggg ggggggg</div>
  <div>hhhhh hhhhhhh</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во время анимации перемещения `:hover` не срабатывает. Браузер ждет ее окончания и эта проблема известна https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246304. 
Ничего тут не поделаешь.

Возможное решение: кастомно ставить класс `.hover` под элемент, над которым находится мышь:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.your-class').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        speed: 4000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        cssEase: 'linear'
    });
    var lastCoordinates = [0, 0];
    $(document).off('mousemove').mousemove(function (e) {
        lastCoordinates = [e.pageX, e.pageY];
    });
    $(document).on('touchmove', function (e) {
        //lastCoordinates = [e.pageX, e.pageY];
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.hover').removeClass('hover');
        var element = $(document.elementFromPoint(lastCoordinates[0],
            lastCoordinates[1]));
        if (element.closest('.your-class').length) {
            element.addClass('hover')
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

```css
.your-class div {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
}
.your-class div.hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 55px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 55px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 20px 55px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.14/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.14/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="your-class">
  <div>aaaaa aaaaaaa</div>
  <div>bbbbb bbbbbbb</div>
  <div>ccccc ccccccc</div>
  <div>ddddd ddddddd</div>
  <div>eeeee eeeeeee</div>
  <div>fffff fffffff</div>
  <div>ggggg ggggggg</div>
  <div>hhhhh hhhhhhh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: здесь используэтся mousemove тоесть на мобильных устройствах работать не будет? и как убрать .hover если я не навожу на елемент, потому что сейчас один раз навел и с таймаутом будет работать постоянно даже если я уберу указатель мыши?

Comment: @YuriyChaban на мобильном девайсе :hover работает при клике. Вы можете повесить $('.slick-track').on('touchstart') тоже действие, что и внутри mousemove обработчика.

Comment: и как убрать .hover если я не навожу на елемент, потому что сейчас один раз навел и с таймаутом будет работать постоянно даже если я уберу указатель мыши? Если не сложно, помогите сделать так, чтоб убирался .hover если указатель мыши убран с елемента. Ответ я отмечу как правильный, все остальное что я прошу не касается мого вопроса а просто как дополнение, но то что не убирается .hover это есть проблема

Comment: @YuriyChaban отредактировал сообщение. по поводу мобильных устройств, то сами проверьте как это должно работать в хроме -> toggle device toolbar. Ибо на смартфонах  курсор не двигается. на данный момент hover стоит на месте последнего тача. как должно работать правильно работать - это я не знаю.

Comment: спасибо, работает отлично

Comment: как можно избежать добавления класа к каждому елементу при наведении на странице, тоесть если использовать document то соответсвенно по всему документу будет рассчитываться координаты, но нужно только в контейнере слайдера. Я заменяю  $(document).off('mousemove') на $('.your-class').off('mousemove') то осшибок нет, но когда я заменяю $(document.elementFromPoint на var myClass = $('.your-class'); $(myClass.elementFromPoint  тогда возникаэт осшибка что elementFromPoint не функция. 
Подсумирую, вопрос в том, как сделать определение координат только в нужном контейнере?

Comment: @YuriyChaban обновил код :)