# Slick slider: навигация при наведении на точки

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js, slider-slick.js

При стандартной реализации,slick-slider перелистывается при клике, мне же необходимо, чтобы слайды менялись не при клике на навигационные точки, а при наведении на них.

```
  $('#slider-1').slick({

      dots: true,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,
      autoplay: false,

  });
```

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/694963/256824 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/766463/256824

Comment: `$('.slider').on('mouseenter', '.slick-dots button', function(event) {
  $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).parent().index());
});`

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Оставьте ответ и я выберу вас победителем.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если разобрались, то напишите самостоятельно. Не торопитесь с принятием ответа.

Comment: @РустамГимранов почему не хотите ответить?)

Comment: @doox911, потому что лентяй.

Comment: Тут и отвечать нечего. Просто скопируйте ваш комментарий в ответ и я приму его. Мне все понятно, я уже разобрался как работает и кастомизировал для своего проекта. Никаких дополнительных пояснений, комментариев, примеров мне не нужно уже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для переключения на конкретно заданный слайд можно использовать [метод](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#methods) `slickGoTo`.

Синтаксис метода:

```
$('.your-element').slick('slickGoTo', index, [, dontAnimate]);
```

Параметры:

- `index` - индекс слайда, на который будет выполнен переход. Целое число.
- `dontAnimate` - пропуск анимации. Булево значение. Значение по умолчанию - `false`.

---

По умолчанию в качестве точек навигации плагин создаёт HTML разметку примерно следующего содержания:

```html
<ul class="slick-dots">
  <li class="slick-active">
    <button type="button" ...>1</button>
  </li>

  <!-- Остальные элементы `li` списка `ul` -->
</ul>
```

Событие `mouseenter` генерируются, когда курсор мыши переходит на элемент. В качестве такого элемента я выбрал кнопку `button`: при наведении на неё меняется стиль курсора.

Ниже демка с использованием двух слайдеров.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  autoplay: false,

  // dotsClass: 'slick-dots'
});

$('.slider').on('mouseenter', '.slick-dots button', function(event) {
  $(this).parents('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).parent().index());
});
```

```css
.page {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 2.5rem auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Стили плагина -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

<div class="page">
  <div class="slider">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/ff9ff3/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+1" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/feca57/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+2" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/ff6b6b/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+3" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/48dbfb/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+4" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/1dd1a1/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+5" />
  </div>

  <div class="slider">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/1dd1a1/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+1" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/48dbfb/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+2" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/ff6b6b/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+3" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/feca57/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+4" />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x120/ff9ff3/FFFFFF?text=Изображение+5" />
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Скрипты плагина-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если бы меня попросили решить эту задачу в максимально сжатые сроки, я выбрал бы подобное решение:

```
$('.slick-dots button').mouseenter(function (e) {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn[0].click();
});
```

Т.е. просто отлавливаем событие появления курсора мыши (`mouseenter`) над навигационным элементом слайдера (`.slick-dots button`) и кликаем на него, повесив всю остальную работу на Slick.

p.s.: накидал простой пример - https://jsfiddle.net/Denisdude/dkL312o8/23/