# Совет по готовому решению слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, поиск-библиотек

Товарищи, верстаю макет. Дошел до части со слайдером.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не подскажете возможно есть какой-то похожий готовый вариант слайдера, чтобы сделать его быстро?
Знаю только один slick slider. попробовал переделать его, но как-то не вышло расположить на странице только 3 элемента, и засветлить неактивные.

Comment: врядли лучше слик слайдера найдешь, это все решается через css
child 0.5 opacity - last 0.5 opacity

Comment: или побокам полупрозрачные блоки

Comment: у слика есть демо на страничке, копируйте пример ковыряйте верстку

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToScroll: 1,               
  dots: false,
  arrows:false,
  infinite: true, 
  variableWidth: true,  
  arrows:true,
  nextArrow: '.project__next',
  prevArrow: '.project__prev',
});
```

```css
#container{
 max-width: 950px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.slider{
 max-width:600px;margin: 20px auto;
} 
.project__next img, .project__prev img{
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
}
img {
  max-width: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #fff;

}
.slick-slide {
padding-top:20px;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
transition: all .3s;
}
.slick-center {
  padding-top:0;
}
.slick-center img {
  max-width:160px;
}
.slick-active {
opacity:.3;
pointer-events: all;
}
.slick-center {
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="project__prev">
        <img src="https://media.msufcu.org/publicsites/publicsite/icons/arrow_left_gray.png">
      </div>
      <div class="slider">

        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>
        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>
        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>
        <div class="project__foto">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">

        </div>

  </div>

    <div class="project__next">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/5/C/M/6/i/right-grey-arrow.svg">
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием [Owl Carousel 2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

Для плавности используется `transform: scale`

Пример

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 0,
  center: true,
  dots: false,
  nav: true,
  responsiveClass: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 3
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 3
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.owl-carousel img {
  max-width: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.owl-item .item {
  transition: transform .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
}

.owl-item.active .item {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: scale(.8);
}

.owl-item.center .item {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512300872216-54ef7791f155?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=18b9a3e2bbc98783513eea4cb4b6b9bd&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов - добавил вариант с owl-carousel

Comment: Получилось не плохо, поставил плюс. Главное, что когда я вам минус ставил, то ставил не молча, в отличии от некоторых, как например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1031895/256824).